# Nrwl / Nx dependency error between nest and angular apps

Tags: angular, nestjs, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to create a monorepo project wirh nrwl / nx.
I followed the tutorial on nx web site and i do the following steps :

- Creation of an empty workspace

  `npx create-nx-workspace`
- Creation of an angular app named frontend

  `nx g @nrwl/angular:application`
- Creation of a nest app named backend

  `nx g @nrwl/nest:application frontend`

I want to shared all model interfaces between backend and frontend, so i created a library with the command :

```
`nx g @nrwl/workspace:lib data`
```

I use one of the models interface defined in my data library in the backend app with the @projectName/data import and it's ok i can build and run the backend.

The type definition causing the problem is :

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type AgentDocument = Agent & Document;

@Schema()
export class Agent{
  @Prop()
  name : string
  @Prop()
  imgUrl : string;
}

export const AgentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Agent);
```

After testing it is the import of @nestjs/mongoose which cause the error of the frontend on build.

Can i tell to the frontend to ignore this import when importing the model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer,

The problem came from decorators used to define shema for mongoose.

Decorators are not compatoble with lib sharing on front.

There is one workaround described here :

https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3322

But it does not work entirely with mongoose because of the SchemaFactory object used in my model definition.

Instead i rewrite my model to remove decorator like this :

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface Agent {
  name : string,
  imgUrl : string,
}

export const AgentSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
  name : String,
  imgUrl : String,
})

export type AgentDocument = Agent & Document;
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. For some reason when I would serve the angular app I was getting a ton of errors referencing nestjs. This was because I was importing the @Injectable from nestjs instead of angular in the angular application. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Use the interface as just that, in your library.  Then in NestJS, Angular, etc., write the concrete class which then 'implements' the interface.  This way the definition is shared for other code to find, but each application can have its own decorators and other requirements.  The library can also hold functions that can be imported (or directly called), which can then be shared across applications.